# VS2015 MVC5 new project referencing existing project files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I designed a web app using VS2015, MVC5 and EF6.  I host this app for many different customers.  I designed the app to use partial views, etc for customer-specific info, styles, etc.  How do I create a new project referencing the original "template" but including only those files specific to each customer?

The files that are different for each customer include:

```
Images/CompanyLogo.bmp
Views/CustomerSpecific/*  (right now, just 1 partial view)
Views/Documents/* (right now just 2 document files)
Content/CustomerStyles.css
web.config
```

I want to set it up so that if I need to do any maintenance on the primary project, the changes would be reflected in their project "auto-magically".

Comment: One possible way is using TFS(Team Foundation Server). You can create separate branches of your App for each cllient, then set up customer-specific info, iconss, styles, etc.. And create a Branch for the Main App. This technique will allow you to develop for each client separately and/or common features. When you need to create common feature you will create it in the Main App and then Merge it with other branches. When you need customer specific - you will code on the Branch of the client. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181423.aspx) you can find more info.

Comment: Instead of referencing files inside different project, why don't you just drive everything from a database. Store Images inside /Images folder and save a unique identifier into database about which image belongs to which customer. Same with view all the customer related information should be save into database.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I don't have access to Team Foundation Server.  I'm a sole-proprietor using VS2015 Community.  I'll have to think about the database option.  Seems logical but a bit too complicated.  With my other client-server application (PowerBuilder 12) I just created a few folders with code libraries (core, foundation, graphics, etc) then with each customer I create a new application, include those library files and add the custom libraries.  The core, foundation and graphics rarely if ever change.  Re-compiling simply re-compiles the custom libraries.